# Excel advanced multiple conditions formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need to write an IF in Excel with multiple conditions.

Basically, I need excel to return me this:

IF CR2=>2 and CI2=>2 and CH2=>2 it should return 1

IF CR2=>2 and CI2=>2 and CH2=1 it should return 2;

IF CR2=>2 and CI2=1 and CH2=>2) it should return 2;

IF CR2=>2 and CI2=1 and CH2=>1 it should return 3;

IF CR2=1 and CI2=1 and CH2=1 it should return 4.

I've been trying to get this right but with no success and I think the problem is probably due to the fact that I don't know how I can right the False statements in this case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are more possible combinations, what about those, or are thes the only possible?

Comment: These are the only ones possible

Comment: What should be returned if none of these conditions are met? (Even if that shouldn't be the case, from a programming perspective, this should always be considered.  You can use NA() or ERROR().

Comment: =AND(CR2>=2,CI2>=2,CH2>=2)*1
+AND(CR2>=2,CI2>=2,CH2=1)*2
+AND(CR2>=2,CI2=1,CH2>=2)*2
+AND(CR2>=2,CI2=1,CH2>=1)*3
+AND(CR2=1, CI2=1, CH2=1)*4 - This might work for you but you might run into situations where multiple conditions are true. Anyway, it's a concise way to write the statement IF you can fully ferret out every possible combination.

Comment: Why does it feel like Condition 3 and 4 need work?  That CH2=>1 really needs to read CH2=1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just make a big, ugly, nested-IF-AND statement and figure out how you want to deal with the other possible scenarios (unless they don't happen in your data).

```
=IF(AND(CR2>=2,CI2>=2,CH2>=2), 1, 
IF(AND(CR2>=2,CI2>=2,CH2=1), 2,
IF(AND(CR2>=2,CI2=1,CH2>=2), 2,
IF(AND(CR2>=2,CI2=1,CH2>=1), 3,
IF(AND(CR2=1,CI2=1,CH2=1), 4, "some other thing happened"))))))
```

Comment: Just be careful here if you find yourself needing 8+ conditions.  If not mistaken, nesting IF statements past 8 levels is not possible.

Comment: Good point. I also forgot about IFS(), which I think is easier to read, but I'm not sure if it is available in older versions of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you but you might run into situations where multiple conditions are true. Anyway, it's a concise way to write the statement IF you can fully ferret out every possible combination.

```
=AND(CR2>=2,CI2>=2,CH2>=2)*1 + AND(CR2>=2,CI2>=2,CH2=1)*2 + AND(CR2>=2,CI2=1,CH2>=2)*2 + AND(CR2>=2,CI2=1,CH2>=1)*3 + AND(CR2=1, CI2=1, CH2=1)*4
```

Answer (score 0):

Below formula will give the result as you requested.

```
=IF(AND(CR2 >= 2, CI2 >= 2, CH2 >= 2), 1, IF(AND(CR2 >= 2, CI2 >= 2, CH2 = 1), 2, IF(AND(CR2 >= 2, CI2 = 1, CH2 >= 2), 2, IF(AND(CR2 >=2, CI2 = 1, CH2 >= 1), 1, IF(AND(CR2 = 1, CI2 = 1, CH2 = 1), 4,)))))
```